# Ternary Operator not working properly in C++

Tags: c++, nested, ternary

I have the following code snippet:

```
if (w)
{
    if (b)
    {
        if (c)
            cout << "great!";
        else
            cout << "3";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "2";
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "1";
}
```

I have to use the ternary operator instead. I thought that

```
cout << w ? b ? c ? "great" : "" + 3 : "" + 2 : "" + 1;
```

would be fine. It isn't.

**Edited:**

Even if I use the following code snippet, it still doesn't work properly:

cout << (w ? b ? c ? "great!" : "3" : "2" : "1");

Please try to run the following code:

```
int w =1, b = 1, c = 0;
if (w)
{
    if (b)
    {
        if (c)
            cout << "great!";
        else
            cout << "3";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "2";
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "1";
}   

cout << "  ";

cout << w ? (b ? (c ? "great" : "3") : "2") : "1";
```

Why is the output   3  1 ?

How should I correctly "transform" the code ?

Comment: there is something called braces i.e `{ ... }`. please use them too!

Comment: The expression `"" + 3` doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: what does `"" + 3` mean? write `"3"` if you meant that.

Comment: I love titles like "<basic C++ feature> not working" :)

Comment: I was trying to covert an integer to a string

Comment: Why convert an integer to a string when you can use a string containing what you want directly? Otherwise use e.g. [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: That is not how you convert an integer to a string in C++. "" + 3 has a completely different meaning (which is a terrible useless one that just gives everybody who uses it nasal demons).

Comment: You will also understand why e.g. `"" + 3` doesn't work if you know that a string literal is actually a pointer to the first entry of an array of characters, and what you're doing is adding `3` to this pointer.

Comment: i have edited it...need peer review ;)

Comment: Debugging tip: use values whose origin is discernable - e.g. `cout << w ? b ? c ? "great" : "groovy" : "awesome" : "cool";` would produce the same output as you got.

Comment: @Andrei your still missing the most important pair of brackets: cout << ( w ? ... : "1");

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem. The pair of brackets. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Use braces {} and () accordingly should work.

--> Start using braces in the original code, then replace the "if" with the ternary operator and replace the braces with brackets.

You will get something like this:

```
cout << (w ? (b ? ( c ? "great" : "3") : "2") : "1");
```

not sure I really prefer this approach though...

Comment: You don't need parentheses inside the ternary operators, e.g. `cout << (w ? b ?  c ? "great" : "3" : "2" : "1");`

Comment: No problem - you can lose the other parentheses too - they are harmless, but redundant.

Comment: Let's say that it's easier to read that way (at least for me). I usually prefer easier reading over shorter text.

Comment: Sure - I find it more readable without the parentheses, but everyone's entitled to their opinion. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent ternary expression would be

```
cout << (w ? b ? c ? "great!" : "3" : "2" : "1");
```

However if you are having a hard time figuring out how to write such a nested expression, coworkers are going to have a hard time reading it. Try to prefer readability and correctness to terse one-liners.

Comment: Now add a couple of brackets for clarity and I could almost use this approach... (almost...)

Comment: doesn't do what you think it does though... `<<` got higher precedence so you start off with `(cout << w)`. ternary operators should always use parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you convert an integer to a string in C++. "" + 3 has a completely different meaning (which is a terrible useless one that just gives everybody who uses it nasal demons).

If you correctly converted your integer to a `std::string` there would be nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: He would still have a problem with operator precedence, even if he fixed this. It needs to be: `cout << (w ? b ? c ? "great" : "3" : "2" : "1");`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 w ?
 (
        b ?
        (
                c ?
                (
                        cout << "great!"
                )
                : cout << "3"
        )
        : cout << "2"
 )
 : cout << "1";
```